# prove or disprove $(n+2^k)^{2^k}\equiv 0(\mod 2^{k+1})$

Tags: number-theory

let $n,k$ is positive numbers,$(n,k\ge 5)$

prove or disprove 
$$(n+2^k)^{2^k}\equiv  0(\mod 2^{k+1})$$
My idea: 
$$(n+2^k)^{2^k}=\sum_{j=0}^{2^k}\binom{2^k}{j}n^{2^k-j}(2^k)^{j}=n^{2^k}+2^k\cdot n^{2^k-1}\cdot 2^k+\cdots=n^{2^k}+2^{k+1}A$$
where $A$ is postive integer.

I found
$$2^{k+1}\nmid n^{2^k}$$

this problem is from [How prove this $n^n+47\equiv 0\pmod{2^l}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719870/how-prove-this-nn47-equiv-0-pmod2l)
then I can't prove it.Thank you

Comment: Can you say anything about the expression $(n+2^k)^{2^k}$ if $n$ is an odd number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following paragraph is quoted from the link you provided.

> Now, if $n^n+47\equiv0\pmod{2^l}$, but $n^n+47\not\equiv0\pmod{2^{l+1}}$ we have
>   $$(n+2^l)^{n+2^l}\equiv(n+2^l)^n \pmod{2^{l+1}}$$

I think what you mean is that $$(n+2^k)^{2^k}\equiv 1 \pmod {2^{k+1}}$$ when $n$ is odd.(when $(n+2^l)^{2^l}\equiv 0$ could only give you $(n+2^l)^{n+2^l} \equiv 0$ rather than $(n+2^l)^{n+2^l} \equiv (n+2^l)^n$)

This is equivalent to prove $n^{2^k}\equiv 1$, Use Euler's theorem since $(n,2^{k+1})=1$, we know that $n^{\varphi(2^{k+1})}=n^{2^k}\equiv 1\pmod {2^{k+1}}$